# How to Send Mail Without using Password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to sent mail without using password of the mailid,Currently i use this code to sent mail.....i hardcode the mail id and pwd

i want to pass the frommail and tomail as parameter, and i dont want a password to send a mail

```
        System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("demo@outlook.com", "demo1234");
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = cred;
        smtp.Send(message);
```

Please Help Me

Answer (score 1):

Ignore setting the credentials and use:

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Something like this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc(v=vs.110).aspx#code-snippet-2

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, it allows you to use NetworkCredential but without specifying exact credentials, therefore no need to specify a password

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code which you can use. If you have any question please ask!

```
// Create the Outlook application by using inline initialization.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector oInspector = oMsg.GetInspector;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient oTORecipt = oMsg.Recipients.Add(email);
oTORecipt.Type = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo;
oTORecipt.Resolve();



oMsg.Subject = "Happy Birthday";
oMsg.HTMLBody = body; //copy the HTML msg body taken from the HTML file. Body is a string

string date = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
oMsg.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;

oMsg.Save();
oMsg.Display();

 //Explicitly release objects.
 oMsg = null;
 oApp = null; //This has to be done at the end
```

Remember to add the header file `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`

Comment: I have used the `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` but still I'm getting some errors